# Tight packing of tcolorboxes in multicols environment

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox, multicol

For a formulary, I want to put several (ideally breakable) tcolorboxes in a multicols environment. The following code is a very basic example of what I already did:

```
\documentclass[landscape, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hmargin=1cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbset{
    breakable, % << comment for a different weird behaviour
    % lines before break=5, % << the warning message suggests to increase this value
    frame empty,
    blank,
    left=3mm, right=3mm,
    borderline vertical={1pt}{0pt}{black},
    colbacktitle={black!20},
    coltitle=black,
}

\newtcolorbox[use counter*=subsection]{block}[1][]{before title={\thetcbcounter:~},#1}

% for testing
\usepackage{blindtext}
\NewDocumentCommand{\testbox}{m}{
    \foreach \i in {0,...,#1}{
        \begin{block}[title=This is a test-box]
            \par
            \framebox(\linewidth,1cm){foo}
            
            \framebox(\linewidth,2cm){foo}
            
            \framebox(\linewidth,1.3cm){foo}
        \end{block}
    }
}

\usepackage{multicol}

\title{Box-Packing}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{4}
\maketitle

\section{Foo}
\testbox{4}

\section{Bar}
\testbox{3}

\section{Baz}
\testbox{2}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I get some weird balancing of the columns (mostly direct after a section)
[image: Weird balancing]

Following the suggestion in the warning, and increasing `lines before break` gives the following:
[image: With lines before break increased]

Just for the record: disabling `breakable` wouldn't work either:
[image: no breakable]

Are there any ways to improve the packing of the tcolorboxes in a multicols environment (ideally breakable)?

Comment: Is there any way to improve the question to get more attention? If so, I would like to do it!

Comment: Not saying I can solve your problem, but maybe a sketch of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[image: tabular like]

The problem you are having is one of modular arithmetic! You have a fixed height of a page and you want to insert a set of fixed height boxes into it.  Now and then you get a large remainder and however hard you or multicolumn  tries you will not have a pleasant result. I am not too sure if your choice of multcolumn package is the best. This can be solved with some typography tricks to trick the eye.

If you provide some more information with real data of say 3-4 blocks. I might be able to add some further solutions.

As a starter I provide a simple solution based on your approach.

1. Place the frame  box outside the loop.
2. Coloring the background might give you a bit of better typography.
3. Now and then add some extra skips manually.

A better approach would be to change the approach and start with four boxes to representing the columns (like a tabular}. I would make sure that the top row always contains a section or a phantom section so that the first frameboxes will always line-up. In a way build it up like a tabular environment.

I can come up with a solution, if you provide a bit more real data. I am mostly interested if the frameboxes are of uneven depth.

```
\documentclass[landscape, parskip=half]{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=1cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbset{
    %breakable, % << comment for a different weird behaviour
    % lines before break=5, % << the warning message suggests to increase this value
    frame empty,
    blank,
    left=3mm, right=3mm,
    borderline vertical={1pt}{0pt}{black},
    colbacktitle={black!20},
    coltitle=black,
}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newtcolorbox[use counter*=subsection]{block}[1][]{before title={\thetcbcounter:~},#1}


% for testing
\usepackage{blindtext}
\parindent0pt
\NewDocumentCommand{\testbox}{m}{
        \begin{block}[title=This is a test-box]
        \end{block}
        \foreach \i in {0,...,#1}{%
        \hbox to \linewidth{\hfill\framebox(0.9\linewidth,1cm){foo}\hfill}
         \vskip1.5pt plus0.3pt minus 0.3pt
        }
    \vskip1.5pt plus0.3pt minus 0.3pt
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \formulary_clist 
\clist_gset:Nn \formulary_clist {foo, bar, drug 1, drug 2, drug 3}
\ExplSyntaxOff



\title{Box-Packing}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{4}
%\maketitle

\section{One}
\testbox{4}

\section{Two}
\testbox{3}

\section{Three}
\testbox{2}

\section{Four}
\testbox{4}

\section{Five}
\testbox{3}
\testbox{3}


\section{Six}
\testbox{3}
\testbox{4}

\section{Seven}
\testbox{2}
\vskip2cm

\section{Eight}
\testbox{4}


\section{Ten}
\testbox{3}

\section{Eleven}
\testbox{2}
%\vfill\vfill
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```